# iOS8/Swift: UICollectionViewCell height calculation

Tags: swift, ios8, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

deriving from other posts about this topic i tried the following approach - but somehow "foo" as well as "bar" seem to be nil

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    var foo = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? messageCell

    var bar = foo?.messageText.frame.height

    return CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width-20, bar!+20)

}
```

the class for the custom cell:

```
class messageCell: UICollectionViewCell,UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate,UITextViewDelegate{


@IBOutlet weak var authorLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var timestampLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var messageText: UITextView!



func setCell(authorLabelText:String, messageText:String,timestampLabelText:String) {

    self.authorLabel?.text = authorLabelText
    self.timestampLabel?.text = timestampLabelText
    self.messageText?.text = messageText


    self.messageText.delegate = self
    self.messageText.sizeToFit() //works, i can see different heights when giving a custom color background
    println(self.messageText.frame.height)

    }
}
```

Am I supposed to set the height in my custom cell class? That would make no sense as it isnt rendered yet, wouldn't it?

€dit:
A Screenshot from stopping at "foo":
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`bar` is nil *because* `foo` is nil - that's what the optional chaining "`?`" is doing in that expression. If `collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? MessageCell`**†** is nil, it would imply either:

- There is no cell at that index path, or
- The cell at `indexPath` is not an instance of `MessageCell`

I would suggest it's more likely to be the latter, as those delegate messages shouldn't really call with an invalid index path. Where you register your cell class (either in code, or in the storyboard), are you sure you're registering them as `MessageCell` cells?



**†** *Types should begin with an uppercase character*